# Gradle Spring dependencyManager exclude module from BOM definition

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle Spring [dependency-manager plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) for importing Maven BOM definition in project. And I need to exclude one module defined in BOM.

Will be nice to do something like this, but mavenBom only accept string.

```
dependencyManagement {
     imports {
          mavenBom ('io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
              exclude 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse'
          }
     }
}
```

Is it possible to exclude specific module defined in BOM on some other way?

Answer (score 0):

The imports are only for importing boms so that we can declare dependencies without worrying about the versions

We can exclude particular dependency when actually declaring the dependency from that bom.

For your eg something like:

```
dependencyManagement {
         imports {
              mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.0.1.RELEASE'
         }
    
    }
    dependencies {
            compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'){
                exclude 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core'
            }
    }
```